# "cannot get automation extension" error with chrome 54.0.2840.71

Tags: google-chrome, protractor

protractor version : `1.5.0`

chrome version : `54.0.2840.71 m (64-bit)`

protractor failed to launch chrome with the following error:

`Using ChromeDriver directly...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[launcher] Error: UnknownError: unknown error: cannot get automation extension`

Comment: So it appears that you are using an old version of Protractor. What's the history of this issue? Has this test worked previously and version 54 does not work? Maybe upgrade to the latest version of Protractor?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check your chromeDriver Version and confirm weather it is compatible with your chorme version.

And check this : https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Comment: problem resolved after I updated protractor and webdriver to latest

Answer (score 5):

worked for me like a charm:

- npm update protractor -g (globally update protractor)
- webdriver-manager update

Answer (score 0):

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

options.addArguments("start-maximized");        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/vedavyasa/bank_emulation/test/lib/chromedriver");
 webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);